How to generate the sums of squares of integer partitions for a given non-negative number?
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We can write $n$ as $$n=\sum^k_{i=1}x_i$$ for some set of $k$ natural numbers, $\{x_i\}$, $i=1,\cdots, k$. I wish to find the possible values for $$m=\sum^k_{i=1}x^2_i$$ Here's what I've done so far. First, $x_i=x_i^2\mod 2$ for all $i=1,\cdots,k$, so $n=m\mod 2$. Also, note that the smallest $m$ is $n$ and the largest is $n^2$. Other than the boundaries and parity conditions I haven't found anything that can give me all possible values of $m$ without using a computer. If it's not clear what my question is asking, the following Mathematica code yields the desired set of possible $m$'s...
 Module[{partitions, squaresSums}, partitions = IntegerPartitions[n];
  squaresSums = Total[#^2] & /@ partitions;
  squaresSums
  


Welcome to the community.
If you are focussing on a given partition of n, then just squaring its parts and adding will give you the easy answer.
I would modify your code to Map[#.# &,IntegerPartitions[n]]
You could also start from the count of integers 1 up to n in all integer partitions of n using Elder's theorem (see https://oeis.org/A066633). From there, it's easy to obtain the sum of squares over all partitions of n, not just a selected partition.
